# Receiving partial data from non-blocking socket

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing http server with TCP sockets in C. For some reason, I receive partial data even if I call `read` in loop like this.

```
size_t data_len = 0;
while (auto len = read(sock, buf + data_len, read_buffer_size)) {
  if (len < 0) {
    if(errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
      break;
    }
  }
  data_len += len;
}
```

Socket options I use:

```
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (void *) &new_buf_size, sizeof(new_buf_size));
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (void *) &new_buf_size, sizeof(new_buf_size));
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DONTROUTE, (void *) &turn_on, sizeof(turn_on));
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *) &turn_on, sizeof(turn_on));
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SOCK_NONBLOCK, (void *) &turn_on, sizeof(turn_on));
int flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: You should change the last parameter to `read_buffer_size - data_len` to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, oh, thank you. Missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting it nonblocking then not continuing to read when it would block... so the rest of your data comes in later but you're already out of the loop. Important to remember that TCP is a byte stream and there is no correlation between the number of bytes sent in each write call and the number of bytes read on each read call, other than they will eventually (given infinite time) be the same. You're not giving it infinite time.

Remove the break statement and you'll see that you'll get all your data (though then your loop will never end). You need to define a protocol so you know how much data to expect.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you!

Comment: In other words, you meant `continue` not `break`